# Play2: Best way to deliver JSON content

Tags: java, json, rest, playframework, playframework-2.0

Let's say I have REST like endpoints which return JSON data, e.g. from models in my Java Play application. I've found two ways to create the JSON output:

1. Using JSON templates similar to HTML templates. It could look like this:

   ```
   {
     "name": "${user.name}",
     "id": "${user.id}",
     . . . 
   }
   ```

   What I like about it is the flexibility. I could build a wrapper around the data (for metadata, status messages etc.) with ease. And I easily can influence which things get delivered (things like password fields, timestamps of last login etc. are of course nothing you want to show to the client). A requirement is of course that the content of the template variables should be escaped correctly in order to get valid JSON. What is the best way to do this?
2. The second approach is to serialize the POJO of the model directly into JSON. Of course this is faster and can be done with less effort. In contrast to the template approach, it is perhaps more reliable since it is an automatic process. BUT: how can I exclude data like password and metadata fields? should I construct a new JSON object with the jackson implementation that only contains the relevant data? Or do I have to create a "json-model" for each model class and transform the real model on each request into the json-model before I can serialize it?

Personally, I like the template approach because of its flexibility. But some of you will say, never construct JSON, XML etc. manually. But is this really a problem in this case, what would you recommend?

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention it, yes, Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Java, Jackson let you exclude fields using annotations. See: http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.0.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnore.html